# How to put CALayer on CMSampleBuffer of video data output?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, apple-vision

Here's my code:

```
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, 
     didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, 
            from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {

    guard CMSampleBufferDataIsReady(sampleBuffer) else { return }

    // This is the delegate method for 
    // AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate and 
    // AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate  
}
```

I'm trying to use Vision framework and draw a layer over eyes where I got the success. However I want to record the same.

Comment: Any chance you manage to work it out?

Comment: Yes, I'll post the code as a answer in a while.

Comment: Will happy to see!

Comment: Are you trying to Add the CALayer and save the video or image ? I've implemented face detect and masking the face with recording of it.

Comment: Something like that, but I want to work at the lowest level possible, as close as I can to the buffer

Comment: Ah, i used CIDetector to detect faces and add a mask

Comment: If i put that code, it'll make you confuse. letme see if i can upload it to github.

Comment: any update? Need to do something similar.